# insert a new record in nodejs using sequelize POST method

Tags: node.js, post, methods, insert, sequelize.js

I want to insert a new data in database using sequelize express, without query. I am trying so hard but I didn't get the output... If my code is wrong, then give me a code for insert a new record in db using sequelize express.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
//var request=require('request')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('ganeshdb', 'root', 'welcome123$', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
var users = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    role: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING
});
app.post('/test', function (request, response) {
    return users.create({
        name: request.body.name,
        role: request.body.role,
        email: request.body.email
    }).then(function (users) {
        if (users) {
            response.send(users);
        } else {
            response.status(400).send('Error in insert new record');
        }
    });
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Express server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Getting any error ?

Comment: Could you please add a `.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})` block to the create function and post us error, if it logs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use body-parser

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Example use body-parser:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 
var app = express()
 
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
 
app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

Example:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '100mb', parameterLimit: 1000000 }));

const sequelize = new Sequelize('test_01', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

const users = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    role: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING
});

app.post('/test', function (request, response) {
    return await users.create({
        id: request.body.id,
        name: request.body.name,
        role: request.body.role,
        email: request.body.email
    }).then(function (users) {
        if (users) {
            response.send(users);
        } else {
            response.status(400).send('Error in insert new record');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('Express server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: can u please give me a full code,actually i am new to nodejs,

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: yes sir, can u do me favor.. i want to insert data by seperated files like routes, models, controller like that.. i seen more examples in internet but didnt get proper output.

Comment: sir, give your mail id, i will my project

Comment: uladzislau.vavilau@gmail.com

Comment: i send my project to ur mail, check it